# create-react-app (without ejecting) + bourbon/neat?

Tags: bourbon, neat, node-sass, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I'm rewriting an "old" React prototype that uses Bourbon, it also uses gulp-sass in a gulpfile to inject a node-neat dependency:

```js
var sassOptions = {
    includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths,
};
```

I'd like to use the `create-react-app` boilerplate and have a "simple" workflow for the styles by using an npm script to compile the sass files (also because create-react-app restricts you on that) but I can't figure out how to do that.

```json
"build-css": "node-sass src/styles/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/styles/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
```

I'll probably rewrite the styles in the future using a different approach (maybe use styled components, maybe keep using Sass and dismiss Bourbon entirely) but I just need to port the Sass styles from the old project for now.

Any ideas on integrating create-react-app (without ejecting) and Bourbon/Neat?

Is there a way to get the neat.includePaths bit into the node-sass one-liner script in package.json, for example?

Comment: Minor side note but you should probably swap out `node-neat` for `bourbon-neat`. `node-neat`is a port and tends to be behind the official release.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon-neat

Comment: thanks a lot man. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to check outNeat NPM documentation at https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#installing-with-npm-and-using-a-node-based-asset-pipeline

As an alternative you may want to try http://eyeglass.rocks/ as a way of handling your sass and dependencies. Sadly react is pretty outside of my wheelhouse so that's the best advice I can give.

Comment: hey did you ever end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not evaluate the `includePaths` you need to be able import Bourbon and Neat through the one-liner in `package.json`.

However, you can still use Bourbon +Neat with your non-ejected React app. If you keep your `package.json` changes as described by React [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc), install the gems on your machine and install them locally in your Sass directories where you see fit. As an example;

- /src

  - /styles

    - /vendors

      - /bourbon
      - /neat
      - /other-sass-library
    - /base
    - /layout
    - /...
  - App.js
  - ...

When having the gems installed, you run the commands where you want them installed. `bourbon install --path <some-path>` and `neat install`.

When you can reference Bourbon and Neat this way, it's no problem to simply `@import vendors/bourbon/bourbon` etc.

Of course, this way of managing styles are not on par with the co-located, module thinking of React/Webpack, but sometimes there's definitely a need for a fully controlled Sass styles tree.